# How to get a value that is stored in database in view page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. i need to get the tax value save in settings table and use it in the following view page.
sample_view.php

```
<fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Service price: <?=$service_detail['service_price']?> Rs</label>
          </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Tax Percentage : 14%</label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <?php 
          $tax_percentage=14;
          if(strstr($service_detail['service_tax'],"inclusive")==true) {
            $taxamount=$service_detail['service_price']-($service_detail['service_price']/(1+($tax_percentage/100)));
            $grand=$service_detail['service_price'];
          }
          else {
            $taxamount=($service_detail['service_price']*(1+($tax_percentage/100)))-$service_detail['service_price'];
            $grand=$taxamount+$service_detail['service_price'];
          }
          ?>
            <label for="email">Tax Amount : <?php echo $taxamount; ?> Rs</label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Grand Amount : <?php echo $grand; ?> Rs</label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-actions">
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>admin/service"><button class="btn" type="reset">Back</button></a>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Here in this view page I set the tax percentage by default.But I need to get the value that is available in settings page.How should I code for this. Can someone help me code?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `company_logo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `service_tax` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_tax` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_format` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `time_format` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is my table structure. Here i store the `service tax` and now I need to get this service tax to the previous view file `sample_view.php`
I have a model file with the following function

```
public function get_service_price($id)
     { 
     $this->db->select('service_tax');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('service');
    return $query->row();  
 }
```

Using this function i could get the `service_tax`. I need to get this in view file.How to do it?

Comment: Where is your controller  and model code???

Comment: Better read codeigniter docs or book first. I cant see any MVC here.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: How you call your model file ?? ! mean where is your controller code??

Comment: That is what i need. I do not know it. Can you please help me

Comment: what is `$service_detail['service_tax']` value passing??

Comment: That holds a string whether it is inclusive or exclusive @Abdulla

Answer (score 0):

call model function in controller and then pass return data in views by using `$this->load->view('filename',$data);`

$data variable is an array that contain all data that need to pass to views.

Comment: how could i use that value in view file.How could i use it in   <?php 
          $tax_percentage=14;
          if(strstr($service_detail['service_tax'],"inclusive")==true) {
            $taxamount=$service_detail['service_price']-($service_detail['service_price']/(1+($tax_percentage/100)));
            $grand=$service_detail['service_price'];
          }
          else {
            $taxamount=($service_detail['service_price']*(1+($tax_percentage/100)))-$service_detail['service_price'];
            $grand=$taxamount+$service_detail['service_price'];
          }
          ?>

Comment: $service=$this->model_name->get_service_price($id);  then use                 $data['service_tax']=$service->service_tax; and then use that load function and hence $service_tax will become variable for view file.

Comment: I cant understand it.Which piece of code should I use in View file

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    <?php
        if(!empty($service_detail['service_price']))
        {
        //this to check whether `$service_detail['service_price']` data is set or unset. If set it execute below Query of unset it goes to `else` part

        $tax_percentage=14;
        $tax = $tax_percentage/100;//optimize the calculation

        if($service_detail['service_tax']=='inclusive')//not sure about strstr(),
        {
            $taxamount = $service_detail['service_price'] - ($service_detail['service_price'] / (1 + $tax ));
            $grand = $service_detail['service_price'];
            ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Tax Amount : <?php echo $taxamount; ?> Rs</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Grand Amount : <?php echo $grand; ?> Rs</label>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        $taxamount = ($service_detail['service_price'] * (1+ $tax)) - $service_detail('service_price');
        $grand = $taxamount+$service_detail['service_price'];
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Tax Amount : <?php echo $taxamount; ?> Rs</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Grand Amount : <?php echo $grand; ?> Rs</label>
        </div>
    <?php
    }

    }
    else
    {

    }

?>
```

**EDIT 01**

In Model

```
public function get_tax()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT service_tax FROM settings ");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

In Controller

```
$data['tax'] = $this->model_name->get_tax();

$this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

In view

```
foreach ($tax as $new_tax)
{
    tax_percentage = $new_tax['service_tax'];
}
```

Comment: still i am getting the blank page

Comment: without load view use `die();` place before view

Comment: Array ( [service_detail] => Array ( [service_price] => 5545 [service_tax] => inclusive ) [tax] => Array ( ) ) i am getting this

Comment: ok check your view is correct(name/spell). cz you are getting data.

Comment: but tax array is still returning empty

Comment: so problem is with your model. Check whether arguments are correct

Comment: No i checked it i could get the stored value but still i am getting white page, something wrong with view

Comment: Array ( [service_detail] => Array ( [service_price] => 1000 [service_tax] => ) [tax] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [company_tax13] => 14 ) ) ) i could get this

Comment: oopz sorry my fault. now replace code above in **EDIT 01**

Comment: remove the view code which i give you early and, copy that again and paste it to your view

Comment: there the value of tax_percentage is fixed, i need to get it from controller.I replace the view code with the above code

Comment: still i get a white screen

Comment: no. now it cant be get. did you replace whole code??

Comment: will it take lot of time? I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: what may be the problem?

Comment: this happen only when i go with exclusive. If i choose inclusive i could get the output